# Excel 2010 : vlookup - How to create a column automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have two sheets (let's call them : Sheet 1 and Sheet 2), each one have a table with their own fields.
How can I add this new column with the values ?

If I refer to VLOOKUP documentation :

**lookup_value** : AX (where X is the index of the current row) of Sheet 1
**table_array** : B1 to BZ (where Z is the last row index) of Sheet 2
**column_index** : the 2nd
**range_lookup** : False

For concret illustration:

Whatever field | Generated Vlookup
Bill | N # A
Jenny | Whatever data you want

PS: I accept whatever working answer : VBA script or Pure excel.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you want? It's easier to understand your question if you can post an example of the desired output and input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want, here's what I suspect you're looking for:

Let's pretend your table is in A1:C50. In D1, you'll put your header for the column. In D2, you'll want

```
=Vlookup(A2,'Sheet2'!B1:C50,2,0)
```

Then you can either
1) Double click on the bottom-left hand corner of the cell to have it populate down
2) Drag the cell down with using the bottom left hand corner of the cell
3) If it's actually a table, it'll pull automatically

If this doesn't help, please provide more details

Comment: 2 and 3. Sorry, after too many times with MS SQL in excel 2016, excel 2010 feel strange for me. I need this to create a table pivot but the original way I used only exists in 2013+

Comment: I finally prefer INDEX + MATCH to Vlookup : someone has added a column inside the data I proceded before your edit ^^

Comment: I also like index-match a lot more than vlookup - I'll rarely use vlookup myself. However, for people just starting to learn, and people explicitly asking about vlookup, I'll give the vlookup answer